# pthreadvc is missing C program

Tags: c, codeblocks

I got this message when I tried to run C program includes pthread.h

```
pthreadvc.dll is missing from your computer . 
Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem
```

I reinstalled the code blocks and  I tried to add the dll file using " regsvr32 c:\pthreadvc.dll " command but this message appeared

```
pthreadvc.dll was loaded but the entry point DLLRegisterServer was not found
```

I tried also to put the file directly in "system32 " but with no useful result.

what should I do ?

my os is windows 7 64 bit

Comment: What happened after you added `pthreadvc.dll` in system32?

Comment: Suggestion: learn how to compile from the command line. Make it work on the command line. Learn what codeblocks configs transform to on the command line. Solve your problem =)